# How to delete the comb present below the dates from images with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I actually want to remove the comb below the dates with the help of opencv. Attaching the image for the referance .Till now I am able to remove the horizontal line of the comb with the code given below.`

```
import cv2
import os

image = cv2.imread(r'path to file')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)

repair_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,6))
ver =cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel, iterations=1)

result = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(255 - image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel, iterations=1)


cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imwrite(r"path to image",image)
cv2.waitKey()`
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfxvo.png)

[Image after removing horizontal lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUX6r.jpg)

Comment: I would get manually positions of all lines and put while rectangles in these places - using normal functions. Or would manually measure distance between lines and then I would have to find (even manually) first line and then I could calculate positions for other lines.

Comment: Or I would find all contures and remove contures which have similar height as lines on screen. OR remove all contures with height much smaller then other contures.

Comment: OR check which contures has similar TOP and BOTTOM position (so they have similar height)

Comment: Thanks for reply , Actually I am new to opencv can you provide code snippet, it would be quite helpfull

Answer (score 2):

Vertical lines are probably the smallest contours (with the smallest heights) so I use it to detect them.

Using again `findContours` but with `cv2.RETR_LIST` instead of `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` I get all contours.

For every contour I calculate `height = max(Y) - min(Y)`

If `height` is between 23 and 25 then I have vertical rectangle which I can remove using filled `drawContours`

I had to check `between 23 and 25` because I found 2 smaller contours which I had to skip. Because I had to choose values 23, 25 manually so this method is not so universal.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    #X = c[:,0,0]
    Y = c[:,0,1]

    min_y = min(Y)
    max_y = max(Y)

    height = max_y - min_y

    if 23 <= height <= 25:
        print(f'{max_y:3} - {min_y:3} = {height} <---')
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0,0,255), 2)        # red border
        cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)  # filled 
    else:
        print(f'{max_y:3} - {min_y:3} = {height}')
        
    print('----')
```

Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

---

Full code:

```
import cv2
import os

image = cv2.imread('Cfxvo.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)
    
repair_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,6))
ver = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel, iterations=1)

result = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(255 - image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel, iterations=1)

# --- new code ---

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    X = c[:,0,0]
    Y = c[:,0,1]
    min_y = min(Y)
    max_y = max(Y)
    height = max_y - min_y
    if 23 <= height <= 25:
        print(f'{max_y:3} - {min_y:3} = {height} <---')
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0,0,255), 2)
        cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
    else:
        print(f'{max_y:3} - {min_y:3} = {height}')
        
    print('----')

# ---

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imwrite("output-image.png", image)
cv2.imwrite("output-result.png", result)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also check other values to make sure.
All rectangles have similar `width` 6-7 pixels.
And all have `max_y  =  61`